# Comment: this post is a duplicate

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

Earlier today I flagged a post as duplicate on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804320/route-two-parameters-symfony2).

I intially left a comment saying something like:

> Duplicate of: link to the question

I see this comment has now been deleted.
Is it not welcome to left a comment when a post is a duplicate of another one on top of flagging it?

Comment: When the post has been closed as dup, I think the comment is also removed accordingly.

Comment: Your comment was fine. Go back and look at the question. "Duplicate of" comments are converted to the text at the top when the question is closed.

Comment: Ok I see. Just didn't know it works this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, comments with links to a master question are removed automatically by the system when the question is closed as a duplicate. A banner is added to the top of the question, containing a link to the master.